# How to call a function at different intervals in GSAP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timing, gsap

I have a very basic slideshow as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img class="slide" src="img/slideshow-1.png" >
    <img class="slide" src="img/slideshow-2.png" >
    <img class="slide" src="img/slideshow-3.png" >
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){

    var $slides = $(".slide");          //slides
    var currentSlide = 0;               //keep track on the current slide
    var stayTime = 3;                   //time the slide stays
    var slideTime = 1.3;                //fade in / fade out time

    TweenLite.set($slides.filter(":gt(0)"), {autoAlpha:0}); //we hide all images after the first one
    TweenLite.delayedCall(stayTime, nextSlide);             //start the slideshow

    function nextSlide(){                   
            TweenLite.to( $slides.eq(currentSlide), slideTime, {autoAlpha:0} );     //fade out the old slide
            currentSlide = ++currentSlide % $slides.length;                         //find out the next slide           
            TweenLite.to( $slides.eq(currentSlide), slideTime, {autoAlpha:1} );     //fade in the next slide
            TweenLite.delayedCall(stayTime, nextSlide);                             //wait a couple of seconds before next slide
    }

});
```

As you see it simply shows each image for 3 seconds (stayTime) and then fades it out. Suppose I want to keep the first image for 8 seconds, the second for 6.5 seconds and the third for 3 seconds. I mean stayTime is not the same for all images. How can I achieve that in GSAP or Javascript?

Comment: You mean, how can you decrease the `stayTime` parameter?

Comment: no I mean instead of calling a function at fixed interval, we call it at different intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to convert `stayTime` to an array, one item for each slide.

```
var stayTime = [8, 6.5, 3];
```

and then:

```
TweenLite.delayedCall(stayTime[currentSlide], nextSlide);
```